# How can I test for a Tkinter hover event in the middle of a function?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have a frame. Let's call it frame1. When the mouse hovers over this frame, another frame is created. Let's call it frame2. Frame2 is created right next to frame1. When the mouse leaves frame1, frame2 is destroyed. However, when the mouse hovers over frame2, a variable is changed from a 0 to a 1 to prevent frame2 from being destroyed.

This way, theoretically, frame2 won't be destroyed unless the mouse hovers over something that isn't either of the frames. However, in practice, The event called from the mouse leaving frame1 is always called first, so frame2 is always destroyed before the function that changes the variable can be called.

- Is there a way that the order in which these functions are called can be swapped, so that the variable can be changed before the function to delete frame2 is called?
- If the order must be kept the same, is there a way to re-check for the mouse hovering over frame2 inside the function called to delete frame2?

A simplified example of the code I'm using:

```
def __init__(self):

    def close1(event):
        self.c1 = 1
        if (self.c1 == 1) and (self.c2 == 1):
            self.frame2.destroy()

    def close2(event):
        self.c2 = 1
        if (self.c1 == 1) and (self.c2 == 1):
            self.frame2.destroy()

    def log2(event):
        self.c2 = 0

    def log(event):
        self.c1 = 0
        self.c2 = 1

        self.frame2 = Frame(self.win,height=round(self.wheight/5),width=round(self.wwidth/5),bg='blue')
        self.frame2.place(x=self.wwidth-self.wwidth/5,y=self.wheight/15)
        self.frame2.pack_propagate(0)
        self.frame2.bind("<Enter>", log2)
        self.frame2.bind("<Leave>", close2)

    self.win = Tk()
    self.win.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    self.win.update()
    self.wheight = self.win.winfo_height()
    self.wwidth = self.win.winfo_width()

    self.frame1 = Frame(self.win,height=round(self.wheight/15),width=round(self.wwidth/10),bg='blue')
    self.frame1.place(x=self.wwidth-self.wwidth/10,y=0)
    self.frame1.pack_propagate(0)
    self.frame1.bind("<Enter>", log)
    self.frame1.bind("<Leave>", close1)
```

close1 is the function always called before log2 is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a delay to `close1` being called:

```
self.frame1.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: self.win.after(10, close1, e))
```

This way, `log2` will be called before `close1`, fixing the problem. A delay of 10 ms will also be unnoticeable to the user. You could alter this value, I chose 10 arbitrarily.

I appreciate that this is not a 'clean' solution - there may be a better one!

Comment: I just tried this, but I can't seem to get any functions to work during the delay. I set the time delay to 2 seconds, and included a print statement at the start of each function, then moved my mouse between frame1 and frame2 a few times during the 2-second delay. Nothing was printed.

Comment: @Bill Try adding `e` inside the `after` parameters, as you have `event` as a parameter in `close1`.

Comment: ~SneakyTurtle I misread the initial text, it now works perfectly as intended, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you mark the question as answered?